# Efficient way to manually categorize / tag short texts

Tags: text-processing, keyboard-shortcuts

I have several hundred short snippets of text. I need to view them one at a time and mark each one with one or more tags from a pre-populated list. I'd like to have a piece of software that lets me do this efficiently and entirely from the keyboard.

I'm imagining something that can take a text or csv file with one piece of text per line. It also gets a list of tags that I manually input, or reads them from another file. It shows one piece of text and allows me to apply or remove tags with one keypress per tag (e.g., press 1 to toggle the "this is dialog" tag for this piece of text, press 2 to toggle the "this is in French" tag, etc). When I'm done I can press another key to bring up the next piece of text. The data should be saved to a CSV or another common file format.

I feel like I've seen similar software for Mechanical Turk categorization tasks, but I can't find anything that I could use.

- OS: MacOS or Windows. Webapps also okay.
- Price: Under $20